What is causing Unexpected Keyword 500 error when trying to pass data from URL as a variable using Django?
I am taking an online course and replicate the instructor's code on my Mac in VS Code to help me learn how it works; and this is not a homework problem.  The instructor was showing how to dynamically create responses based on the URL by sending the last part of the url as a variable  to a function that then generates the response.  However , when I try it I get a 500 error.  I have reviewed my code and it looks identical to the instructors, with only added comments.  Fixed paths work fine, i.e.
    path("brian", views.brian, name = "brian"),

works fine, but this fails:
    path("<str:name>", views.greet, name = "greet")

the error is:
[18/Jul/2024 20:50:39] "GET /hello/jim HTTP/1.1" 500 59430
[18/Jul/2024 20:50:41] "GET /hello/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5
Internal Server Error: /hello/jim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/XXX/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: greet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Name'

I created several bits of code: (comments are mine so when I go back to the code later I can understand it)

Created app called hello and added to installed apps in settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = ['hello',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
] # which apps - such as hello to include in web app

2.  Defined path to use in urls.py in hello directory:
from django.urls import path
from . import views
   
urlpatterns =[
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    path("brian", views.brian, name = "brian"),
    path("<str:name>", views.greet, name = "greet")
    ]#returns the function greet from views as a web page for /hello paths, "brian" adds /brian to end of hello as web page to load

3.  Added urlpatterns to urls.py in project root directory
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
   
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include("hello.urls")) # tells django to include urls from urls file in hello
   ]

4.  Defined "greet" function in views.py in hello directory:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")

def brian(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Brian")

def greet(request, new_name):
    return HttpResponse(f"Hello,{new_name}") # fstring - says use the value of {name} in displayed text; parameter name is a returned variable to greet

when I the local server and enter a url such as:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/brian -> works like expected
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/jim -> I get the 500 error I referenced above.

The name of the parameter still needs to be name, so:
def greet(request, name):
    return HttpResponse(f"Hello,{new_name}")

The issue is with url itself.
    path("<str:name>", views.greet, name = "greet")

modify the url like this
path("<str:new_name>", views.greet, name = "greet")

your parameter should match with parameter name mentioned in url
